# Different values for R134a property Tables

Tags: thermodynamics

I need internal energy and volume value for R134a refrigerant, to get the values went through steam tables/property tables for R134a

For a particular steam table

At temperature 30 degree celsius, Specific internal energy = 246.14 kJ/kg, specific Volume of gas = 0.026622 m^3/kg,
[image: for which the snap of table is given below]

For one more steam table from another resource

At temperature 30 degree celsius, Specific internal energy =  394.48 kJ/kg, specific Volume of gas =  0.02671 m^3/kg,
[image: for which the snap of table is given below]

Which table values must be considered and why there is such a difference?

Comment: The tables probably use different reference states for zero internal energy.

Comment: You will generally be interested in internal energy differences rather than absolute values.  Check both tables for "delta values" ... they should both be the same.

Comment: Does the second table have columns for enthalpy and entropy that you are not showing. If it does, how do they compare with the first table. My tables agree with the your first table for enthalpy  and entropy. But my table does not even list internal energy.

Comment: See my the update to my answer to demonstrate that the absolute values of specific internal energy don't matter if you are only interested in the change in the specific internal energy. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Chet Miller pointed out in his comment, the reason could be different zero reference states for internal energy for the two tables. Notice the last sentence of the notes at the bottom of your first table. It reads "The enthalpy and entropy values of saturated liquid are set to zero at -40 C".

But heres the important point: *For all practical purposes it doesn't matter where the zero reference is set and what the specific absolute values are. That's because when we use these tables we are almost always only interested in **changes** in the values of internal energy, enthalpy, and entropy, not the absolute values. For that purpose either table would be ok since changes in these properties should be approximately the same.*

To illustrate, consider the increase in the specific internal energy of the fluid going from 30 C to 40 C for the two tables.

From the first table:

$\Delta u=250.97-246.14=4.83$

From the second table:

$\Delta u=399.46-394.48=4.98$

So you see the change in specific internal energy of the saturated vapor between the same two temperatures is about the same for both tables.

By the way, your first table appears to align with the following table:

https://www.cambridge.org/us/files/2313/6697/5548/Appendix_C.pdf

Note that in this table the zero reference state for the specific enthalpy and specific entropy of saturated liquid is -40 C per the notes in your first table. The zero reference state for the specific internal energy of the saturated liquid falls between -35 C and -40 C.

Hope this helps.